# Value not posting for first row generated with php foreach

Tags: php, html

Need assistance with following code. Value for "customer_id" is not posting after hitting submit for the first generated row only. the second and following work as intended.

Other pages use this same format for deleting, but do not redirect to another page like this one does. No issues with deleting.

```
<html>
    <!-- the body section -->
    <body>
        <main>
            <section>
                <!-- display a table of customers -->
                <h2>Results</h2>
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>Email Address</th>
                        <th>City</th>
                        <th>&nbsp;</th>
                    </tr>
                    <?php foreach($customers as $cus) : ?>
                    <tr>
                        <td><?php echo $cus['firstName'].' '.$cus['lastName']; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $cus['email']; ?></td>
                        <td class="right"><?php echo $cus['city']; ?></td>
                        <td><form action="view_and_update.php" method="post" id="search">
                            <input type="text" name="customer_id" value="<?php echo $cus['customerID']; ?>">
                            <input name="submit" type="submit" value="Select">
                            <?php include "redirect.php";?>
                            </form></td>
                    </tr>
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                </table>
            </section>
        </main>
    </body>
</html>
```

redirect.php looks like this:

```
<?php

    if(isset($_POST["submit"])){
        //  To redirect form on a particular page
        header("Location: view_and_update.php");
    }

?>
```

Any assistance is greatly appreciated. This is for an assignment, and we are using the languages as specified with XAMPP/myphpadmin. No problem retrieving, editing, adding, or deleting data in any other circumstance. This is the only problem page.

Comment: When you hit submit, the view_and_update.php page is posted as expected, no need to use redirect. 

Eg. the body posted to view_and_update.php will contain: 

`customer_id=123&submit=Select`

Comment: This is true, I can remove the redirect, but it still will not post the customer id to the view_and_update.php page for the first row unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

By using the following example code I got the correct post to view_and_update.php

It has to be something else, it is not the code.

```
<?php $customers = [ 
['firstName' => 'Alice', 'lastName' => 'Al', 'email' => 'alison@domain.com', 'city' => 'MyCity', 'customerID' => 123],
['firstName' => 'Bob', 'lastName' => 'Bo', 'email' => 'bob@domain.com', 'city' => 'MyCity', 'customerID' => 124]
]; ?>
<html>
<!-- the body section -->
<body>
    <main>
        <section>
            <!-- display a table of customers -->
            <h2>Results</h2>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Email Address</th>
                    <th>City</th>
                    <th>&nbsp;</th>
                </tr>
                <?php foreach($customers as $cus) : ?>
                <tr>
                    <td><?php echo $cus['firstName'].' '.$cus['lastName']; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $cus['email']; ?></td>
                    <td class="right"><?php echo $cus['city']; ?></td>
                    <td><form action="view_and_update.php" method="post" id="search">
                        <input type="text" name="customer_id" value="<?php echo $cus['customerID']; ?>">
                        <input name="submit" type="submit" value="Select">
                        </form></td>
                </tr>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
            </table>
        </section>
    </main>
</body>
</html>
```